# How to change color hue in XNA?

Tags: c#, colors, xna, argb

I have a color of class `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color`. How can I change its hue (or get a new color with slightly different hue). Should I convert it to `System.Drawing.Color`, then somehow change it and convert back? I can't find any useful information on this anywhere.

**EDIT**
Example:
I have red color R:255, G:0, B:0. Now I want to get slightly more orange color. Then if I get this color and transform it again I'll get even more orange color, then after some transformations I'll go to yellow, green etc. I don't know exact values of ARGB of each color and I don't need them. I just need to change hue of a color by some factor (for example 10 degrees).

Comment: well then, your Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Color seems to be represented in RGB.  If you want another representation, than you can learn how that representation works and write a function to calculate RGB values based off of that.

Comment: I don't believe there is really a simple way of doing this, but according to Wikipedia one can compute the Hue of a color from RGB ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue#Computing_hue_from_RGB )

I don't know if you can go from a Hue to RGB easily though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx), you can pass whatever RGB(A) values you want into the XNA color class constructor.  You can also use the R, B, and G properties to change them afterwards

example:

```
Color myColor = new Color(150, 100, 100);

myColor.R = 200
```

that example will change a red to a slightly deeper red.

An example of making a color go from Red to orange to yellow to green would be

```
Color myColor = new Color(255, 0, 0);

for(int i=0; i<255; i++)
{
    myColor.R--;
    myColor.G++
}
```

Red and Green make yellow, so higher numbers of red will make it redder, higher numbers of green will make it greener.  same of both numbers make it redder.

You can change color incrementally in other ways too, so long as you know how the primary colors of light work.
You're never ever going to find a function called `Color.MakeRedder()` or `Color.MakeGreener()`  It will always focus on some sort of mathmatical representation of the color, (RBG is most common but there are other representations)

If you want to convert Hue to RBG [Here is a guide on how to do it](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html)

What would probably be easiest is to keep track of a `System.Drawing.Color` class as your base color class, and modify your XNA `Color` Class based on your `System.Drawing.Color` class accordingly.

If you want to get really adventurous, you can see if it is possible to make a class that extends(inherits from) `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color`, override the R, G, and B properties, so that they are based off of an underlying `System.Drawing.Color` object

Comment: But I need to slightly change hue of my color. So from orange to to more red for example. Not defining the color from scratch.

Comment: @Episodex then just modify the RBG properties

Comment: Your example is good to solve my example. But it's not generic :(. I can't use it with other color combinations and all starting colors are possible. I'll try with converting to `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: I thought about more like `color.Hue += 10` as hue is a number between 0 and 360 as far as I know.

Comment: @Episodex  I just posted a link to http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html in my answer.  that has algorithms from converting from HSV(hue based) to RBG.  You should be able to use that to get the representation that you want

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it now :).

Comment: @Episodex  I also added a suggestion about how to use `System.Drawing.Color` to  keep track of your RGB values.

Comment: I'll get back to this problem tomorrow and decide what to do. +1 for the algorithms!

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [A](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.a%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx) [R](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.r%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx) [G](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.g%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx) [B](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.b%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx) properties and change the values to get different nyansers.

For example:

```
Color color = new Color(0,0,0);
//Then you can change the argb properties:
color.A = 10;
color.R = 15;
color.G = 9;
color.B = 25;
```

---

If I understand you need something like this:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static void Increase(this Color color, int value)
    {
        if(color.R >= color.G && color.R >= color.B)
           color.R += value;
        else if(color.G >= color.R && color.G >= color.B)
           color.G += value;
        else
           color.B += value;
    }

    public static void Decrease(this Color color, int value)
    {
        if(color.R <= color.G && color.R <= color.B)
           color.R -= value;
        else if(color.G <= color.R && color.G <= color.B)
           color.G -= value;
        else
           color.B -= value;
    }
}
```

---

Then:

```
Color myColor = new Color(10,0,0);
myColor.Increase(10);
//or
myColor.Decrease(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking this solution.

Comment: It works decently when I switch `>=` to `<=` in `Increase()` method. Otherwise it just stops on one color - try your code on #FF0000. When I corrected this it is changing colors but not full spectrum. Anyway, thanks and +1 :).

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found this post which has C++ code:

http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

I've modified the code to be C#, to have an IncreaseHueBy method, and to fix a few bugs:

```
 public static void IncreaseHueBy(ref Color color, float value, out float hue)
 {
     float h, s, v;

     RgbToHsv(color.R, color.G, color.B, out h, out s, out v);
     h += value;

     float r, g, b;

     HsvToRgb(h, s, v, out r, out g, out b);


     color.R = (byte)(r);
     color.G = (byte)(g);
     color.B = (byte)(b);

     hue = h;
 }

 static void  RgbToHsv(float r, float g, float b, out float h, out float s, out float v)
 {
     float min, max, delta;
     min = System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(r, g), b);
     max = System.Math.Max(System.Math.Max(r, g), b);
     v = max;               // v
     delta = max - min;
     if (max != 0)
     {
         s = delta / max;       // s

         if (r == max)
             h = (g - b) / delta;       // between yellow & magenta
         else if (g == max)
             h = 2 + (b - r) / delta;   // between cyan & yellow
         else
             h = 4 + (r - g) / delta;   // between magenta & cyan
         h *= 60;               // degrees
         if (h < 0)
             h += 360;
     }
     else
     {
         // r = g = b = 0       // s = 0, v is undefined
         s = 0;
         h = -1;
     }

 }
 static void HsvToRgb(float h, float s, float v, out float r, out float g, out float b)
 {
     // Keeps h from going over 360
     h = h - ((int)(h / 360) * 360);

     int i;
     float f, p, q, t;
     if (s == 0)
     {
         // achromatic (grey)
         r = g = b = v;
         return;
     }
     h /= 60;           // sector 0 to 5

     i = (int)h;
     f = h - i;         // factorial part of h
     p = v * (1 - s);
     q = v * (1 - s * f);
     t = v * (1 - s * (1 - f));
     switch (i)
     {
         case 0:
             r = v;
             g = t;
             b = p;
             break;
         case 1:
             r = q;
             g = v;
             b = p;
             break;
         case 2:
             r = p;
             g = v;
             b = t;
             break;
         case 3:
             r = p;
             g = q;
             b = v;
             break;
         case 4:
             r = t;
             g = p;
             b = v;
             break;
         default:       // case 5:
             r = v;
             g = p;
             b = q;
             break;
     }
 }
```

I tested it by using a value of 1 to increase the hue by 1 every frame and it worked fairly well.  Notice there may be some rounding errors.